# sql insert statement using sql transaction not working

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, transactions

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GlobalData.GetConnectionString());

string queryDepartment = null;
if (rbtnYes.Checked == true)
{
    if (rbtnMale.Checked == true)
    {
        queryDepartment = 
@"BEGIN TRY 
    BEGIN TRAN 
    insert into UserDetails 
       values('" + Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text) + "','" + txtFullName.Text + "','" + txtPassword.Text + "','" + txtUserName.Text + "','" + cbDepartment.SelectedValue.ToString() + "','" + txtContactAddress.Text + "','" + Convert.ToInt64(txtContactNumber.Text.ToString()) + "','" + txtContactEmail.Text + "',CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE),'" + rbtnYes.Text + "',null,'" + rbtnMale.Text + "','" + Convert.ToInt64(txtSalary.Text.ToString()) + @"'); 
    insert into Users 
       values('" + GlobalData.UsersID_AddUsers + "','" + GlobalData.RoleID_AddUsers + "','" + txtUserName.Text + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text) + @"'); 
    COMMIT TRAN 
  END TRY 
  BEGIN CATCH 
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage 
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
  END CATCH";
    }
}
```

i am trying to insert records using sql transaction into two table from c# code but it is not working.

while the same statement i am inserting in sql table using sql management software its working.

Comment: "*but it is not working*" is not a valid SQL Server error message.

Comment: Where do you execute your query? please provide the code

Comment: Can you please provide us the full `sql server error message`..??

Comment: Why are you editing the question again and again..?

Comment: And maybe have a look at the security topic about sql injections...

Comment: @VishalSuthar some formatting and forgot two @...

Comment: no errors or exception are coming out of it....no records affected nothing....

Comment: First, the way you are doing this in not safe. You should use parameters, as explained [here](http://blog.divergencehosting.com/2009/04/09/using-parameters-parameterized-queries-database-interactions-cshar-vbnet/). Take a look at the example and change your code, try it again and if it doesn't work let us know the error message you are getting and what your code looks like.

Comment: Looks like you're inserting a value into a surrogate primary field ...

Comment: @Matten The `@` in front of the string wasn't in the original question.

Comment: @OlafDietsche but it is required if the string spans multiple lines....... And a one liner as 6000 chars wide sql string is not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL starts with a `BEGIN` but has no matching `END`.  You do not need the `BEGIN` - remove it.

Comment: The statement starts with `BEGIN TRY`, AFAICS.

Comment: It does now, but didn't originally.  The query would have errored before.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said there are no errors come out then i guess this is the problems, your condition doesnt match, would you mind to put a debugged point to check is your condition matches to call your insert function?

```
if (rbtnYes.Checked == true)

if (rbtnMale.Checked == true)
```

Comment: how you execute your query? would you mind to show it? i cant see any execution part at your code, what can i see it u put your query into a string :(

Answer (score 0):

Thank You Every One I have Solved My Problem My Own.........
the problem is the

```
         GlobalData.RoleID_AddUsers is 0..
```

but because of sql try catch its not showing me the error....or catching the exception....
but when i removed the sql try catch...then its start throwing the exception saying that foreign key violation....and bla bla........and i adjust the code as per the requirement....
and problem solved......:)